# copy items from a list on one condition

Tags: c#, list, genetic-algorithm, grasshopper

I am trying to copy items from a list to another list on one condition. 
I have three lists. First list contains for example 10 lists of points, second list contains the total distance (cost or fitness) of each list (10 lists -> 10 total distances).

Here a picture: 
first list contains 10 lists (each list contains points) - second list 'fitness'
[image]
Third list is empty and should be filled with items on one condition. First I added up all values in the second list. 
Example with the numbers above: totalFitness = 4847 + 5153 + 5577 + 5324...

The condition to add list of points out of the first List to the third list is: 
for example ----------> (Fitness[0] / totalFitness) <= ratio.

But it is not working, here you can see the code I tried:

```
class  RunGA 
{
  public static List<List<Point3d>> createGenerations(List<List<Point3d>> firstGeneration, List<int> firstFitness, int generationSize)
  {
   List<List<Point3d>> currentGeneration = new List<List<Point3d>>();

   int totalFitness;
   int actualFitness;
   totalFitness = firstFitness[0] + firstFitness[1];
   double ratio = 1 / 10;

   for(int k = 2; k < firstFitness.Count; k++)
   {
    actualFitness = firstFitness[k];
    totalFitness += actualFitness;
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < firstFitness.Count; i++)
   {
    double selected = firstFitness[i] / totalFitness;
    if(selected < ratio)
    {
     currentGeneration.Add(firstGeneration[i]);
    }
   }
   return currentGeneration;
  }
}
```

The third list is still empty. If I change the condition to: `if(selected <= ratio)`
 then the whole list of points in the first list are being copied to the third list. However what I want to copy is: the list of points which has the 'best' fitness.

What is it that I'm doing wrong? I have absolutely no clue and I tried already a few changes, but it is still not working. I would appreciate it if you can consider that I'm a beginner.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: LINQ Union, Where, Sum, Aggregate methods would certainly help in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for this problem.

I still have these data:

List1:

1. ListOfPoints = a
2. ListOfPoints = b
3. ListOfPoints = c
4. ListOfPoints = d

List2:

1. Fitness of a
2. Fitness of b
3. Fitness of c
4. Fitness of d

What I wanted to achieve was: Take those ListOfPoints, which has the best Fitness and put them into a List3. All the rest ListOfPoints, put them into another List4.

This is the solution I thought of: 
put List1 as Keys and List2 as Values into a Dictionary and sort it via LINQ. Now transfer the sorted Keys into a List3. With a for- Loop put the first half of the sorted List into List4 and the second half into List5.

Here is my Code:

```
List<List<Point3d>> currentGeneration = handoverPopulation.ToList();
List<double> currentFitness = handoverFitness.ToList();
Dictionary<List<Point3d>, double> dict = new Dictionary<List<Point3d>, double>();
foreach(List<Point3d> key in currentGeneration)
{
  foreach(double valuee in currentFitness)
  {
    if(!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
      if(!dict.ContainsValue(valuee))
      {dict.Add(key, valuee);}
    }
  }
}
var item = from pair in dict orderby pair.Value ascending select pair;
List<List<Point3d>> currentGenerationSorted = new List<List<Point3d>>();
currentGenerationSorted = item.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();

List<List<Point3d>> newGeneration = new List<List<Point3d>>();
List<List<Point3d>> newGenerationExtra = new List<List<Point3d>>();

int p = currentGenerationSorted.Count / 2;
for(int i = 0; i < p; i++)
{newGeneration.Add(currentGenerationSorted[i]);}

for(int j = p; j < currentGenerationSorted.Count; j++)
{newGenerationExtra.Add(currentGenerationSorted[j]);}
```

Hope this helps others who face the same problem.